# JSON Parser CPU Timeout error

Tags: apex, json, webservices

I have two classes that parse a json webservice callout response. One class parses a sinlge response result and the other class parses multiple response results. The primary difference between the two classes is whether the json result is a list or a single result. I was trying to combine into one parser class by moving the class that parses a single result into the class that handles parsing the list of results. However, when I tried merging the code and running the webservice that returns the single result, I'm getting a CPU timeout error that just infinitely loops and the getCurrentToken() method is returning null. I'm not getting the full debug results because the log is truncating several of my debug lines.

I'm trying to determine what is causing the infinite loop and get back the single result without the CPU timeout error.

Here is the parser class for the single result:

```
public class SingleResultParser {

    public Result result {get;set;}

    public SingleResultParser(JSONParser parser) {
        while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                String text = parser.getText();
                if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                    if (text == 'result') {
                        result = new Result(parser);
                    } else {
                        System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'SingleResultParser consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                        consumeObject(parser);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Result {
        public String number_Z {get;set;} // in json: number
        public String short_description {get;set;} 
        public String resolved_by {get;set;} 
        public String closed_at {get;set;} 
        public String comments_and_work_notes {get;set;} 
        public String description {get;set;} 
        public String closed_by {get;set;} 
        public String assigned_to {get;set;} 
        public String sys_id {get; set;}

        public Result(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'number') {
                            number_Z = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'short_description') {
                            short_description = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'resolved_by') {
                            resolved_by = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'closed_at') {
                            closed_at = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'comments_and_work_notes') {
                            comments_and_work_notes = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'description') {
                            description = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'closed_by') {
                            closed_by = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'assigned_to') {
                            assigned_to = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'sys_id') {
                            sys_id = parser.getText();
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Result consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static SingleResultParser parse(String json) {
        System.JSONParser parser = System.JSON.createParser(json);
        return new SingleResultParser(parser);
    }

    public static void consumeObject(System.JSONParser parser) {
        Integer depth = 0;
        do {
            System.JSONToken curr = parser.getCurrentToken();
            if (curr == System.JSONToken.START_OBJECT || 
                curr == System.JSONToken.START_ARRAY) {
                depth++;
            } else if (curr == System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT ||
                curr == System.JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
                depth--;
            }
        } while (depth > 0 && parser.nextToken() != null);
    }
}
```

Here is the parser class for the list result:

```
public class ListResulParser {
    public List<Result> result {get;set;} 

    public ListResulParser (JSONParser parser) {
        while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                String text = parser.getText();
                if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                    if (text == 'result') {
                        result = arrayOfResult(parser);
                    } else {
                        System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'ListResulParser consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                        consumeObject(parser);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static ListResulParser  parse(String json) {
        System.JSONParser parser = System.JSON.createParser(json);
        return new ListResulParser (parser);
    }

    public static void consumeObject(System.JSONParser parser) {
        Integer depth = 0;
        do {
            System.JSONToken curr = parser.getCurrentToken();
            if (curr == System.JSONToken.START_OBJECT || 
                curr == System.JSONToken.START_ARRAY) {
                depth++;
            } else if (curr == System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT ||
                curr == System.JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
                depth--;
            }
        } while (depth > 0 && parser.nextToken() != null);
    }

    private static List<Result> arrayOfResult(System.JSONParser p) {
        List<Result> res = new List<Result>();
        if (p.getCurrentToken() == null) p.nextToken();
        while (p.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_ARRAY) {
            res.add(new Result(p));
        }
        return res;
    }

    public class Result {
        public String u_substate {get;set;} 
        public String number_Z {get;set;} // in json: number
        public String sys_id {get;set;} 
        public String comments {get;set;} 
        public String work_notes_list {get;set;} 
        public String state {get;set;} 
        public String assigned_to {get;set;} 
        public String file_name {get;set;}
        public String download_link {get;set;}
        public String content_type {get;set;}
        public String table_sys_id {get;set;}
        public String table_name {get;set;}
        /*
        public String short_description {get;set;} 
        public String resolved_by {get;set;} 
        public String closed_at {get;set;} 
        public String comments_and_work_notes {get;set;} 
        public String description {get;set;} 
        public String closed_by {get;set;}
        */

        public Result(JSONParser parser) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == System.JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                    String text = parser.getText();
                    if (parser.nextToken() != System.JSONToken.VALUE_NULL) {
                        if (text == 'u_substate') {
                            u_substate = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'number') {
                            number_Z = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'sys_id') {
                            sys_id = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'comments') {
                            comments = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'work_notes_list') {
                            work_notes_list = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'state') {
                            state = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'assigned_to') {
                            assigned_to = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'file_name') {
                            file_name = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'download_link') {
                            download_link = parser.getText();                       
                        } else if (text == 'content_type') {
                            content_type = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'table_sys_id') {
                            table_sys_id = parser.getText();
                        } else if (text == 'table_name') {
                            table_name = parser.getText();                        
                        /*} else if (text == 'short_description') {
                            short_description = parser.getText();                        
                        } else if (text == 'resolved_by') {
                            resolved_by = parser.getText();                        
                        } else if (text == 'closed_at') {
                            closed_at = parser.getText();                        
                        } else if (text == 'comments_and_work_notes') {
                            comments_and_work_notes = parser.getText();                        
                        } else if (text == 'description') {
                            description = parser.getText();                        
                        } else if (text == 'closed_by') {
                            closed_by = parser.getText();*/                        
                        } else {
                            System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, 'Result consuming unrecognized property: '+text);
                            consumeObject(parser);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The commented out code is the merged code from the singleResult class. When I execute the callout that returns a single json response, the error is thrown on the if branch immediately after the starting while loop where getCurrentToken() method returns null. If I run the webservice where the callout returns a list of results, the code runs fine.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using `JSONParser` instead of simply using `JSON.deserialize()`?

Comment: I initially tried using `JSON.deserialize()` and was hitting issues with the attributes that were coming back in the response. I ended up using the JSON2Apex tool.